# WCF Reuse Types not raising PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wcf

I add proxies of a service with the **Add Service Reference** function in Visual Studio to my project. I have also a shared assembly (Client, Server) which I tag as a **Reuse types in assembly**. The reused objects didn't have the common setters like

```
   set {
         if ((this.PropertyNameField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.PropertyNameField = value;
           ----->   this.RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyName");
          }
       }
```

Instead there is only an auto-property like setter without a PropertyChanged event:

```
   set {
         this.PropertyNameField = value;
       }
```

Is there any configuration option that i am missing?

Edit:
The reused types inherits from a baseobject which implements *INotifyPropertyChanged* and is also in the shared assembly.

Comment: How do you generate the **Reuse types in assembly** ?

Comment: I am creating a silverlight application, so the shared assembly is a silverlight class library in which the objects inserted as **Add as Link** from a common class library.

Comment: why don't you put the call to `base.RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyName");` ?

Comment: Because i am autogenerating my proxies and i would always adjust the autogenerated proxies after an **Update Service Reference**

Comment: That's what i wanted to know when i asked how do you generate them ;)

Comment: Check for Service reference configuration should be something there

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is only a checkbox **Always generate message contracts** which does not creates my desired setters.

Comment: Check if the Collection Types are the same in the configuration of the service reference

Comment: They are the same. Changing from ObserveableCollection to List doesn't effect the Proxies.

Comment: Maybe you should work on creating your own Generator there are some outthere ;)

Comment: could you recommend one?

Comment: Before getting to such a big work, could you try this ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756369(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this vexing problem myself.  I haven't found a fix for the root issue that prevents the **INotifyPropertyChanged** implementation in classes deriving from types in referenced assemblies, but I have found a workaround.  It still requires some modification to the reference.cs any time the service reference is updated, but it is far simpler than having to add the **RaisePropertyChanged** logic to all the property setters manually.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with **Reuse types in assembly selected**.

1. After you've added the Service Reference initially, enable the "show all files" option on the project
2. Expand the service reference entry in Solution Explorer to expose the underlying files
3. Open the Reference.svcmap file and change the

   ```
   <ExcludedTypes />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <ExcludedTypes>
     <ExcludedType TypeName="ReusedBaseClass" />
   </ExcludedTypes>
   ```

   where **ReusedBaseClass** is the class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged in the shared assembly.  This allows all other types to be reused, but disables reuse of the **ReusedBaseClass** that is causing the issue.
4. Choose the Update Service Reference option on your Service Reference
5. The reference.cs will now have the property setters with the **RaisePropertyChanged** logic present
6. Now do a search and replace operation to replace the local implementation of **ReusedBaseClass** in reference.cs with the fully qualified **ReusedBasedClass** from the shared assembly.